# Storing circle in GeoJSON for OpenLayers 3?

Tags: openlayers, geojson, circle

I am loading my layers from external files - I am using geojson format for it, but it's not necessary - I can use any available format.

Is there a way, how to store a circle (ol.geom.Circle) in the geojson file?

Or is there any other file format, which can be directly used in OpenLayers 3 as layer source and which can include a circle definition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of more googling and trial - error approach I found I there are now other ways than:

1) Generate a circle myself as Polygon using sin/cos functions

2) Use Point geometry with appropriate radius attribute

Answer (score -3):

You can do this

```
ol.interaction.Draw.createRegularPolygon(0);
```